# My Android library using other dependecies couldn't resolve when build

Tags: android, dependencies

I created a sdk, publish it on bintray and get a dependency of my sdk but when i used my library dependency in any of client app then it failed to resolve dependency used in my library project.
Like I used dependency of RxJava , retrofit, glide , viewpager-2 etc into my library project which is uploaded on bitray and provide a dependency and this dependency i am using into my another client app.

Comment: before build and publish to bintray in `build.gradle` file of your sdk replace `implementation` to `api`

Comment: Tried, but didn't work.

Comment: Add link to your lib